# bundle install json installation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, bundler

I'm using the ruby on rails tutorial here:

> http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-one#top

and I ran into problems when using the bundle exec rake db:migrate command. It said

> Could not find json-1.6.3 in any of the sources.

So I used the command `gem install json -v '1.6.3'`, and everything seemed to work fine. Then I tried running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` again, and it failed with the same message, could not find json.

I believe a clue to the problem is that when I use the command `bundle install`, this message pops up when trying to install json 1.6.3:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/Users/chuckyuan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make
Makefile:148: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/chuckyuan/Documents/rails_projects/sample_app/db:migrate/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/chuckyuan/Documents/rails_projects/sample_app/db:migrate/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.3/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.6.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.6.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I create a new rails project and run the same commands, everything works. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On Ruby 1.8.7, you'll need to install a gem. However, in Ruby 1.9.2, the json gem is bundled with the core Ruby distribution. So, if you're using 1.9.2, you're probably all set. If you're on 1.8.7, you'll need to install a gem.

Comment: thats what I would have expected, except the message says that json isn't there, even after I install the gem.